# Django: using a custom method to create a new object from a ModelForm, is this ok?

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a model, `MyModel`, with a manager `MyModelManager`, which has a `create_mymodel(....)` method:

```
def create_mymodel(self, foo, bar):
    new_obj = MyModel(
        foo = foo,
        bar = bar,
        # the rest of the fields are calculated
    )
    new_obj.save()
    return new_obj
```

Elsewhere I have a `ModelForm` for creating new `MyModel` objects.

In the view that handles the form submission, I don't want to repeat all the calculations that the `create_mymodel(foo, bar)` method already does, so can I just do this?

```
form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    MyModel.objects.create_myModel(new_obj.foo, new_obj.bar)
```

From the docs, I'm concerned about what [the docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) about using `f.save(commit=False)`, as I'm not sure how it affects my situation, specifically the `f.save_m2m()` thing.

Comment: Calculate the fields values, and then call `create()` from the parent with all the values you want to pass in there.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear.  I'm already doing the calculations in create(), I don't want to duplicate that code.  My concern is using `form.save(commit=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I'll put the reaction here instead of the comments, so I can add some code examples. I can think about two possible options, but I am not sure how feasible they are (since I dont know the rest of your codebase).

first one - you can use `form.save(commit=False)` as mentioned, but isntead of using a special function in manager, you'll do something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    new_obj.calculate_the_other_fields()
    new_obj.save()
```

^ where `calculate_the_other_fields()` is a method, which calculates and set the "other values" you mentioned (it will also help you split your code into a more smaller pieces to follow Single Responsiblity Principle). Then you'll just call `save()`, and it will create the db record for you the same way as `create_mymodel` would achieve.

other option:

just override `create()` in the manager. Check if you have enough data for calculating the values, and calculate them (otherwise skip the calculation), and then call `create()` from the parent. Then you can use just this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_obj = form.save()
```

Comment: Calling `form.save()` does not call the Manager's `create()` method, so the second approach doesn't work.